# Market overview trading platforms (with OTC)

Tags: fixed-income, software, order-execution

I am searching for a trading platform for a client. It must include control of trading limits (per user and with regard to the clients portfolio), connection to Bloomberg data, ability to value offered trades on fixed income products (plain vanilla and callables). No derivatives, and only occasionally equity. Trading is very low frequency, < 50 per day. About 99% of the assets are hold to maturity. I would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Look into OLF's Findur http://www.olf.com/software/financial-capital.html
highly customizable trading platform, will not give you everything you mentioned out of the gate but has capability to get there with some development effort

Answer (score 0):

ION's MarketView will do a lot of that too, but they didn't have equity coverage last time I looked. Historically the firm came out of the inter dealer EGB market (MTS).